# For react native, is there a module like backbone forms?

Tags: forms, react-native

Is there a react native module that allows you to generate form very fast? like XLForm for iOS and Backbone Form for backbone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out this library.

https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a module that provides that functionality
https://github.com/MichaelCereda/react-native-form-generator